# How to load authenticated user on client with cookies/session from Service Stack AuthService?

Tags: rest, silverlight-5.0, servicestack

I'm using Silverlight 5 to consume ServiceStack REST services with JsonServiceClient and for now it's ok.

At this moment, I'm able to login/logout in ServiceStack hosted in Asp.Net at the path /api.

But after I'm logged in, if the user refreshes the browser's current page where Silverlight is hosted, the Silverlight application is reloaded and the session/cookie info is gone away, forcing the user to login/password again. It's a undesired behavior.

On the server side, I'm using the Default CredentialsProvider:

```
var appSettings = new AppSettings();
var credentialsProvuder = new CredentialsAuthProvider(appSettings);

//Default route: /auth/{provider}
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
new IAuthProvider[] { credentialsProvuder }));
```

On the client, I'm setting RememberMe = true:

```
    public static void TryLogin(string userName, string password, bool rememberMe, Action<AuthResponse, Exception> callBack)
    {
        AuthDto.UserName = userName;
        AuthDto.Password = password;
        AuthDto.RememberMe = rememberMe;
        Client.SendAsync<AuthResponse>(AuthDto, r => TryLoginResponse(callBack, r, null),
                         (r, e) => TryLoginResponse(callBack, r, e));
    }
```

To test a service, I'm using the default Hello Service provided by the NuGet template. Also I've put an [Authenticate] attribute on the class and it's working fine (the service is autorized only after I'm logged in).

Checking the source code of JsonServiceClient, I discovered that the CookieContainer is created after the first request.

I've tried to make a dummy call to the server just in order to see if the server resends the information to the browser, so the JsonServiceClient populates the cookiecontainer with authenticated user info, but no sucess.

My question is: How to get authenticated again on the client, since it was previously authenticated ? Is there a way to the server re-send the cookies/sessions when I call some method ( HTTP GET server/api/auth/GetUser? ) ??

EDIT

After some time inspecting source code of AsyncServiceClient class, I've found:

// Assembly ServiceStack.Common.3.8.3\lib\sl5\ServiceStack.Common.dll

```
  HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) (this.UseBrowserHttpHandling ? WebRequestCreator.BrowserHttp : WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp).Create(new Uri(uriString));
  if (this.StoreCookies && !this.UseBrowserHttpHandling)
  {
    if (this.ShareCookiesWithBrowser)
    {
      if (this.CookieContainer == null)
        this.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
      this.CookieContainer.SetCookies(new Uri(this.BaseUri), HtmlPage.Document.Cookies);
    }
    webRequest.CookieContainer = this.CookieContainer;
  }
```

As found in the above code, the AsyncServiceClient checks for the CookieContainer before each request and if it's null , sets the Cookies from the WebClient of Silverlight to the browser.

Ok , now we are ok with cookies, as I'm sure they are sent from client to the browser.

So, how re-authenticate the user based on existent X-UAId without resending usernames and passwords ?

I would like if in client, I send an empty GET to the AuthService and the service verify cookie, sessions and automatically return a response to the JsonServiceClient indicating that the user is authenticated.

What I want is similar to WCF Ria Services "WebContext.Current.Authentication.LoadUser()" that does the request to the server, if the user on the server is authenticated then returns the current user.

Comment: another issue is after DELETE /auth/logout, the X-UAId cookie is not set to be removed. Maybe I must inherit CredentialsAuthProvider to fix what is missing.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

This might be a bit late, but I had the same problem, and the problem lies within the AsyncServiceClient. When the authentication fails the client sends another request with BasicAuthentication headers added. However when this second request is created in this line

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/ServiceClient.Web/AsyncServiceClient.cs#L405

then CookieStore is not set, and therefore the cookies are not stored when the server responds. After the above line a put this in:

```
if (StoreCookies)
{
    requestState.WebRequest.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
}
```